# Survey Kits for Political Affiliation?

Tags: political-psychology

Are there any widely used suites for measuring a subject's political views? Looking for something commonly cited beyond web quiz time sink quality.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE.  When you mention *political affiliation* do you mean affiliation to specific political parties, or whether they follow a left or right political standpoint?  Maybe you are referring to different kinds of politics such as democracy, dictatorship, monarchy,republican, communism, socialism, marxism, liberal, conservative... Could you please elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: I'd imagine specific affiliation would be easy to kit out, I was thinking more about stance on common political issues such as taxation, war etc. which I guess would fall under left vs right standpoints

Comment: I don't see how they would be easy to standardize, given that political issues differ per region and time period.  In an experiment I worked on recently, we selected some issues from the Post Election Survey portion of the Canadian Election Study (CES), which is publicly available on the [Canadian Opinion Research Archive](https://www.queensu.ca/cora/home), based on how polarized respondents were.